# Edit deterministic value in WinForms desktop application project to avoid error CS8357

Tags: c#, winforms, versioning

In C# WinForms desktop application, according [The specified version string contains wildcards, which are not compatible with determinism](https://marinovdh.wordpress.com/2018/10/22/68/) I've to change `<Deterministic>True</Deterministic>` to `false` in `myproj.csproj`

to increment version with asterisk:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.*")]
```

and avoid:

> Error CS8357  The specified version string contains wildcards, which
> are not compatible with determinism. Either remove wildcards from the
> version string, or disable determinism for this compilation

but I can't find `xml` document with `<Deterministic>True</Deterministic>` in the project, as it is shown in  here [The specified version string contains wildcards, which are not compatible with determinism](https://msm2020-sc.blogspot.com/2019/04/the-specified-version-string-contains.html)

Comment: I would imagine that `true` is the default so you should just add that line to the project with the value `false`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Hello! problem was to find this document, so I have opened it separately in editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to look for an `XML` file.

The document you are looking for is the `.csproj` of the project.

There, under the tag `<PropertyGroup>`, you can place `<Deterministic>False</Deterministic>`

The `<Deterministic>False</Deterministic>` does not exist in the file, because default value is set to True.

Just add it to `.csproj` like the examples in the links you added.

Comment: Hello, yes and to see document I've to open it separately in editor